# how to make a curved design in constraintLayout as given below

Tags: android, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout, android-drawable, curve

[image]

How to make this curved view having text inside, in constraint Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a background to your parent layout of the textview like this

```
android:background="@drawable/my_bg"
```

and create `my_bg.xml` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Adjust the values as per your requirement-->
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"/>
    <solid
        android:color="@color/your_color"/>

</shape>
```